# Finding steering angle of a car given distance travelled, and how far the car ends up offset from a straight line?

Tags: geometry, arc-length

**Problem**: 
I have a semi-autonomous vehicle that needs it's steering adjusted.  I can attempt to send it in a "straight line" of distance $(l)$ -- but unless it's steering is perfect, it will veer from this imaginary straight line.  At the end of $(l)$, the vehicle ends up offset from the intended straight path by $(x)$ units.  The path length $(l)$, and length of vehicle from axle to axle $(b)$ are both variables, and I am assuming that the steering angle $\theta$ and also arc radius $(r)$ remain constant during transit.  [Photo of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zZ4q.jpg)

**What I've tried**:
Started with the radius of the turn from the wheel angle and vehicle length

$$r = \frac{b}{\sin\theta}$$

and subbed this into an equation of a circle, offset to one side by (r),

$$\left(x-\left(\frac{b}{\sin\theta}\right)\right)^2 + y^2 = \left(\frac{b}{\sin\theta}\right)^2$$

and then solved for $\theta$:

$$\theta = \operatorname{arcsin}\left(\frac{2bx}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$
and as far as I can tell, this is correct given a {x,y} endpoint, however, I have {x,l}.  $y$ will only be the same as $l$ if vehicle drives perfectly straight -- which kind of makes this equation useless to me as it stands.

How can I solve for the angle of the drive wheel using arc length instead of $y$?

Comment: Assume a velocity and than the angle will provide a closing velocity in the direction that lead to the "error".

Comment: Little confused by your comment.  This problem should have nothing to do with velocity.

Comment: The direction is not really tangent and as result there are two components - one tangent and one perpendicular to the tangent. Your equation is not right in my opinion. When the car stands nothing happens. When the car moves you see the steering issue. The steering problem causes a component in the direction of the circle center.

Comment: The drive wheel is always tangent to the circle of the path of the vehicle.  It doesn't matter if the vehicle is stopped or moving, the angle of the wheels remain the same, I'm still not following what you're saying.  The equation does work for x,y, as stated in the problem - I just won't have a "y" in the future.

Comment: If I understand correct your question, you are interested in the angle of the wheels that makes this non-straight line movement. Right?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for how many degrees the steering is offset from straight.  This problem is easier to think about in something like a tricycle where the front wheel is a single point.